# how to use submit button with ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my Asp mvc project I want to add company to database  without refreshing the page.
How can I do it with ajax. I want to submit data and return to the same page without refresh.
 this is a part of my code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   
"multipart/form-data" }))

{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)      

 <fieldset>       

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom_company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom_company)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom_company)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.desc_company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.desc_company)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.desc_company)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.datedebut_company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datedebut_company)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.datedebut_company)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.datefin_company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datefin_company)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.datefin_company)
    </div>
    <p>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Create" /> 

    </p>
   </fieldset>
   }
```

Any help please